# Youtube Video freezes on clicking fullscreen mode in android webview

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview, fullscreen

I am able to play YouTube video in android webview but when i click on "fullscreen" mode of youtube,video freezes but i can still hear the audio.
I have set **PluginsEnabled** to **true** and **PluginState.ON** for webview.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this properties, this might help

set the `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in application tag in android manifest.

and set all this properties to webview

```
        articleView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        articleView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        articleView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.766.0 Safari/534.36");
```

Hope this helps